# Why is my flask web app not working properly? I can't find any errors myself

Tags: python, html, flask

So I tried to write my first flask web application and the website isn't working. Here is my application.py. I have already tried to get the input. Is a second web page in case of error necessary? Because the website itself isn't running in my IDE and I can't make out any errors.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import requests
import json
from tempfile import mkdtemp
from flask_session import Session
import random

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = mkdtemp()
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

# import permutation module
from itertools import permutations as prm

scrambled_word = list(str(raw_input("Input your jumbled word: ")))

# empty lists that will be appended to later
prm_list = []
possible_words = []

# take each permutation of the input and put in a list
for i in prm(scrambled_word):
  prm_list.append("".join(i))
  print i

def check(x, y):

   # open list of words
    dictionary = file('words.txt')

    # check each line in the dictionary against each item
    # in the list of permutations and add it to another empty list if it's a match
    for line in dictionary:
        for i in x:
            if i+'\n' == line:
                y.append(i)


check(prm_list, possible_words)

# delete duplicates
possible_words = list(set(possible_words))

# print out possible words
if len(possible_words) == 0 or len(possible_words) == 1 or len(possible_words) == 2 or len(possible_words) == 3:
    print "No match found"
else:
    for i in possible_words:
        print "Possible Word for Jumbled Word is: " + i


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    # make sure that method is POST
    if request.method == "POST":
        app_id = 'fbea320c'
        app_key = '436eab6eae3dbeec6ec311328b9ff7dd'
        language = 'en'

    if request.form.get("Word")
        return render_template("final.html")
```

and here is my final.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <style>
    input{
          max-width: 350px;
    }

    select{
       max-width: 400px;
    }

    #ABC {
        background-color: black;
        position: absolute;
        width: 95%;
      }

    #imh {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50%;
    }

    .centered {
      position: absolute;
      top: 25%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      color: #ffffff;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Word Finder</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="/static/jumble.jpeg" id="imh">
    <div class="centered"><font size="7">Jumble Solver</font><font size="4"><p>Unscramble words!</p></font></div>
    <div class="container">
      <br><div class="row">
        <center><h1>Enter a Word</h1></center><br><br></div><div class="row">
        <div class="inpot"><center>
          <form method="post" action="/">
              <div class="form-group">
              {% if a == 0 %}
              <input type="text" name="Word" id="Word" autofocus autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a Word" onclick="return IsEmpty()" value="{{ j }}"></div>
              {% else %}
              <input type="text" name="Word" id="Word" autofocus autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a Word"/></div>
              {% endif %}
            <div class="form-group">
                     </div><input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input class="btn btn-danger" name="submit" value="next" type="submit"></button></form>
            <div class="row">
        <div class=" text-center">
          <h3>Search up any word!</h3>
          <p>With our jumble solver you can unscramble any mix of letters!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                  </div></div>
    </div></div></font></body></html>
```

i'm pretty new to coding, and i can't figure out what's going wrong

Comment: have you tried `app.run()` at the end of your script?

Comment: yeah it just says "Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."

Comment: You could put your code into functions and execute these in your console. Use some `print()` to check whether there is an error or not. Btw there is an error in your loop `for i in prm(scrambled_word):
  prm_list.append("".join(i))
  print i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to run your code, so I made some modifications to make it run on my python 3.7 in the windows operating system. The following modifications and corrections:

1- use `input` instead of `raw_input`

2- use:

```
    f = open("words.txt", "r")
    dictionary = f.readlines()
```

instead of `file('words.txt')`

3- and of course use `print(something)` instead of `print something`.

4- adding to the end of your code the run command:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=1)
```

5- Indentation in the function `def check(x, y):` should be corrected `

6- Adding the missing `:` in `if request.form.get("Word")`

Finally, the program runs, **but** you use input from console like `raw_input` or `input`, meanwhile, you run `Flask` web server, so you should use forms to get the user inputs.

It would be good if add a sample input data and some lines of the file `words.txt`

Good Luck: